# How to create a local development environment for an existing Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp, staging

I need to set up a development environment for an existing wordpress website.

What I need to do is to somehow mirror the existing website so I can make changes to it before it goes online.

What is the best practice? I need to have exactly the same plugins and theme on it, as well its content. I was thinking that I could use MAMP for it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Setup a local environment, install wordpress, copy your database and use it locally, no real science or best practices on that end

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by copy the database? How do I do it with wordpress? Does all the plugins come with it then?

Comment: You can do it from your phpMyAdmin admin panel. Wordpress is just a CMS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mirror WordPress development environment and live site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868827/how-to-mirror-wordpress-development-environment-and-live-site)

Comment: Just download the whole http root, to your local dev env, make a db dump and import the dump.  change the wb config that it can connect to your db and your good to go, no need for external plugins or bloatware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this;

1. Install a plugin "Duplicator"
2. Backup your website
3. Download your backup & installer file to your PC
4. Copy the backup and installer file to your local server
5. Now run yourdomain.com/installer.php to complete the migration.

For more: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/create-backup-package/

Comment: I tried using Duplicator Pro before on my computer and when it was almost at 99% I got a timeout error :( And I tried it several times.