# How can I move wordpress.com site to new host?

Tags: wordpress

I have a site on wordpress.com that is expiring at the end of October and I would like to host this myself but not sure what I need to do, to move this onto a new wordpress site I have downloaded on my localhost.

I have gone into the backend and downloaded the Export Content file (xml file) along with the media library but I am guessing I now need to somehow import this into the new Wordpress site I have on my localhost.

I understand that I will lose the template and the look but I am not too fussed about that and will be building a new template myself but just need to get around this before I can get started.

Would really appreciate any advice to get me going.

Please bear in mind that I have no access to the database or the web files and this is the reason I was trying to understand the steps I need to take to replicate the site on a new version of wordpress but with content/theme of the existing site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mirror WordPress development environment and live site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868827/how-to-mirror-wordpress-development-environment-and-live-site). This question is about having a copy of the site on a dev environment, but the ultimate goal is the same - move an exact copy of a WP website to another hosting location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For migration you can use this plugin [All in One Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

You will not loose anything, this plugin will handle your front-end and back-end too.

Comment: Thanks fasstechies, I will give that a go. FluffyKitten, thanks for the link, but I don't have access to the database as its live on wordpress.com. I will try the All in One Migration plugin and see how I get on.

Comment: Unfortunately can't install any plugins : (

Comment: Thanks fasstechies, I managed to used All in One Migration and this fixed the issues I was having.