# Migrate staging WordPress site (from a subdomain) to production (the main domain)

Tags: wordpress

I have a new Wordpress site (a staging site) on a subdomain and I want to release it, replacing my current Wordpress site on the main domain.

My developer, who has since gone AWOL (hence I'm doing it), copied the prod WP site to the subdomain, where the theme changed, most of the pages were altered, etc - basically creating a new site, intended to replace my current site.

I have the site on staging basically ready, 301s set up, more or less good to go.

The question is how do I "release" this to production?

My initial thought was just to copy all of the staging directory and folders, overwriting the current production (backed up, of course). The folder structure is almost the same, although I have a folder named after my domain in the Public_html folder, which contains 1 file called Index.php. This doesn't exist in the subdomain folder structure.

However, I'm unsure how that would affect the images. Some of the images on staging point to the production URLs - all those posts/pages where the images haven't altered still point to prod ever since the initial copy from prod to the subdomain.

New images/pages point to the staging site URLs.

I also have differences with internal links; some point to the current prod URLs, some point to Staging URLs.

Therefore, if I simply move all of the staging subdomain folders to the main domain will this cause a problem with my images (and to a lesser extent, because simpler to fix, the internal links)?

Any advice on how best to proceed? For example should I put all images into the current prod site, point all of my staging to those images on prod, and not copy over the image folder from staging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mirror WordPress development environment and live site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868827/how-to-mirror-wordpress-development-environment-and-live-site)

Comment: I don't think so - I don't want to copy the staging site, I want to move it to production (public_html?). But have the mixed up URLs to also consider, not sure how to handle the images.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is :) You want to copy the existing working site on staging, move it to the production location and set it up to work with on the new location - including updating the URLs, paths, included files, links in the posts & plugins, database, htaccess, WP config etc. etc. I've developed dozens of WP sites and migrated them from development, staging and production servers and that answer is exactly what you need to do to get it working. It will set up all those settings I mentioned for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. For the images then, should I make sure all images on staging are pointing to the staging database? Make sure there is nothing on staging pointing to the current production?

Comment: If you use a plugin like Duplicator it will copy literally *everything* for you, images included, and change all the links to point from staging to production. The only issue you might run into is if you've a lots of images - in that case you can exclude them from the Duplicator build and manually copy them across, Duplicator will still fix all the links. But try it out for yourself! Use it to set up a copy of the site on another staging server, or even a subfolder on the existing one. Then let me know if you the answer linked above needs more info or instruction so it's helpful to others :)

Comment: Thanks. So you have indirectly answered my question about the images - they need to all start on staging where they would then copy across. So first step before anything is to get the Prod images copied into Staging, where I'll then copy them back again...Not sure why the developer didn't copy all of them into staging when he was working on this.

Comment: If the image URLs already point to the production server then there is no need to copy them across and back - Duplicator will only update instances of the staging server URL with the production server URL - it won't touch anything else.

Comment: Wish I read this earlier - now the entire staging site is only pointing to staging URLs and the staging database. Therefore to release this to prod I guess I need a clean install of wordpress? Does Duplicator take everything with it, plugins, themes, content, the works?

Comment: Yes Duplicator can copy everything you need for the entire site by default, including all the plugin & theme files. Or you can copy just some of it by excluding files that are already on the destination server. It's very flexible. However if you're unsure it's always safest to copy everything so there are no missing files or discrepancies between versions (e.g. if you updated the theme or plugins on your staging server then the production server will have old files which could clash with the information with the staging database).

Comment: Thanks for all of your help with this. Duplicator made this very straightforward. Thanks again. must appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help! Can you let me know if there is any information I can add to the answer of the question I linked to, so that it would help other users understand better that it is the way to do this?